# How can I extract a subset Spark dataframe from an original dataframe in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (result of `df.show()`):

```
  auctionid|   bid|   bidtime|           bidder|bidderrate|openbid|
|1638843936| 500.0|0.47836804|        kona-java|       181|  500.0
|1638843936| 800.0| 0.8263889|           doc213|        60|  500.0
|1638843936| 600.0| 3.7611227|             zmxu|         7|  500.0
|1638843936|1500.0| 5.2263775|      carloss8055|         5|  500.0
|1638843936|1600.0|  6.570625|          jdrinaz|         6|  500.0
|1638843936|1550.0| 6.8929167|      carloss8055|         5|  500.0
|1638843936|1625.0| 6.8931136|      carloss8055|         5|  500.0
|1638844464| 300.0| 1.8111342|          aprefer|        58|  300.0
|1638844464| 305.0| 3.2126737|        19750926o|         3|  300.0
|1638844464| 450.0| 4.1657987|         coharley|        30|  300.0
|1638844464| 450.0| 6.7363195|        adammurry|         5|  300.0
|1638844464| 500.0| 6.7364697|        adammurry|         5|  300.0
|1638844464|505.78| 6.9881945|        19750926o|         3|  300.0
|1638844464| 551.0| 6.9896526|        19750926o|         3|  300.0
|1638844464| 570.0| 6.9931483|        19750926o|         3|  300.0
|1638844464| 601.0| 6.9939003|        19750926o|         3|  300.0
|1638844464| 610.0|  6.994965|        19750926o|         3|  300.0
|1638844464| 560.0| 6.9953704|            ps138|         5|  300.0
```

I want to create another dataframe (`df1`) starting from `1638843936|1550.0` and ending at `1638844464| 570.0` using Scala Spark, i.e., `df1.show()` should show:

```
|1638843936|1550.0| 6.8929167|      carloss8055|         5|  500.0
|1638843936|1625.0| 6.8931136|      carloss8055|         5|  500.0
|1638844464| 300.0| 1.8111342|          aprefer|        58|  300.0
|1638844464| 305.0| 3.2126737|        19750926o|         3|  300.0
|1638844464| 450.0| 4.1657987|         coharley|        30|  300.0
|1638844464| 450.0| 6.7363195|        adammurry|         5|  300.0
|1638844464| 500.0| 6.7364697|        adammurry|         5|  300.0
|1638844464|505.78| 6.9881945|        19750926o|         3|  300.0
|1638844464| 551.0| 6.9896526|        19750926o|         3|  300.0
|1638844464| 570.0| 6.9931483|        19750926o|         3|  300.0
```

I tried the following code:

```
val df1=df.filter(df("auctionid")===1638843936 && df("bid")===1550.0**)
```

But this is giving me a single value only. What do I have to do so that I can get all lines up to the `1638844464| 570.0` row?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Also what do you mean by "abstracting a subset"?

Comment: If you need rows from perticular row , use zipWithIndex then filter based on zipped column

Comment: How do you determine the order? The show here shows a specific order, however, different runs can potentially give different order (depending on partitioning).

Comment: there is specific order it follows. just wanted to get rows that comes under my starting point to ending point.

Comment: distributed system and particularly spark is not suitable for your requirement

Comment: what is the order? You say it has a specific order but what is it? Are you talking about an order in the source? if so it is lost the minute you move it to a dataframe with multiple partitions. Is it a single partition and you are talking about the order in the partition? Is there an index column?

Comment: @Assaf Mendelson  ya its a single partition. M getting this value as per the timestamp from some source . No cluster involve yet. Just need to fetch the dataframe/ records as per the condition given in the question.

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan i m running this on standalone later do this on cluster. How can i fulfill such requirement

Comment: Then you can simply set the timestamp time as the filter (i.e. > minTime)

Answer (score 0):

Since the dataset is not ordered and it doesn't have any other ordered props it can filter on, I would suggest you create another column of monotonically_increasing_id 's and then fetching the required fields between the upper and lower bounds of the ids

Comment: okay if i add timestamp column here and now the data becomes ordered based on  timestamp value . how can i get the subset now

Comment: try something like filter("time BETWEEN '01-JAN-20XX' AND '10-JAN-20XX").show()